# SSIS Package(File to Postgres Load) Execution Error: there was error trying to establish ODBC connection with DB server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, visual-studio, ssis, odbc

I created a SSIS package for a simple file to Postgres table load. In Visual Studio it ran without any issues. But when its deployed and ran via SQL Agent job its failing stating below error:

[image]

as per the answers I found here and on other sites, I have changed the VS version to lower then the SSIS and changed the runtime to 32 bit in both the places. But its still failing due to the same error. so any suggestions would be of great help and let me know if you need more details, thanks!

ScreenShots:

1. SSIS Package:

[image]

2. Package deployed in SQL Server:

[image]

3. SQL Agent Job:

[image]

Comment: Did you install the ODBC driver on the server? Did you test the ODBC connection on the server?  Are you using an ODBC DSN?  Has the server been rebooted since the install?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for your response! We haven't logged into the server and checked as we don't have access. But the other File to SQL File Server/Oracle load jobs are running fine. Is there a way to test the ODBC connection on server, without logging in?

Comment: The ODBC driver will not be available on the server until someone logs on and installs it.  At that point they should test connectivity in the ODBC Data Sources widget.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft okay we will work with the DBA/Network team on this, thanks for your input!